# Secure dualboot

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

ubuntu 14.04 here.

I'm using a dualboot with windows 7 pro installed first. So far so good, i just succeeded in installing both on the hard disk in separate primary partitions. However when in ubuntu i can see a disk in my launchbar named windows (basically it represents the windows partition). And if i click it i can see the 'C' folder on my windows OS so to speak. And it's not encrypted or anything. I can just get in and delete/ modify/ and all sorts of foul things.
My question is:

1. Is anything shared between the two OS's?
2. How can i find out?
3. what do i do such that absolutely NOTHING is shared between the two OS's (no files, no folders, no applications). This is because i don't want potential threats to transfer from either one to the other. For example i don't want potential spyware (or any virus/malware for that matter) existent on windows to have access to my ubuntu OS.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want 100% nothing shared, then just wipe the windows partition. Crude, I know, but effective. Technically there shouldn't be anything shared. Unless of course you mount/open the windows partition while on ubuntu and open something , like a doc file or something

Comment: i edited my question same time u answered it. i guess that means it's mounted. well, how do i keep it unmounted at all times?

Comment: It's not mounted once you start ubuntu session. For it to mount, you'd have to click on the disk icon in the side bar.

Comment: Windows malware can't affect Ubuntu. It doesn't work like that.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste: theoretically malware could target different OS on the same machine. It's just a rather uncommon setup and desktop Linux (the most common "other" OS) is no worthwhile system for malware authors as either intermediary or final target. I never heard of such malware and I have explained why it won't be done commercially.

Comment: Physical access is root access, the only tool to isolate the two systems wold be full encryption.

Comment: bodhi, what do you mean by physical access?

Answer (score -1):

No there isnt any share between the two OS's.

Ubuntu os will be found in the computer menu(containing the partition you created Ubuntu on) while windows os will be on the windows drive you see on the Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: This isn't entirely accurate, Ubuntu will most likely be able to see Windows, because it has capabilities/support for viewing NTFS. However with Windows, most likely you will not be able to view the ext3/4 partition.